# Resizable UI with resizable elements in Python's Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, resize, scale

I'm working on a UI with Python's Tkinter, but I can't find a way to scale the elements with the window's size. Currently, when I resize the window, nothing moves. What I'm looking to do is have the rows and columns of the program change size (within minimum/maximum sizes) as the window is resized.  Is there any way to do this?

Here's the relevant code I have at the moment:

```
from Tkinter import *

#create window
root = Tk()

#modify root window
root.title("Probability")
root.geometry("1700x800")

#set up app
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

#configure columns and rows
app.columnconfigure(0, minsize=200)
app.columnconfigure(1, minsize=200)
app.columnconfigure(2, minsize=200)
app.columnconfigure(3, minsize=200)
app.columnconfigure(4, minsize=200)
app.columnconfigure(5, minsize=200)
app.columnconfigure(6, minsize=200)
app.columnconfigure(7, minsize=200)
app.rowconfigure(0, minsize=100)
app.rowconfigure(1, minsize=100)
app.rowconfigure(2, minsize=100)
app.rowconfigure(3, minsize=100)
app.rowconfigure(4, minsize=100)
app.rowconfigure(5, minsize=100)
app.rowconfigure(6, minsize=100)
app.rowconfigure(7, minsize=100)
```

Comment: Hello Clayton, welcome to SO.  Are you able to share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: That code isn't useful -- you aren't actually putting any widgets in. Please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you really mean by "scale the elements". Certainly you can arrange widgets on the screen that will grown and shrink as the window resizes. However, they don't scale *per se*. Font sizes won't change automatically, scrollbar buttons won't get bigger or smaller, slider grips won't change size, etc.

Comment: Currently, when I resize the window, nothing moves. What I'm looking to do is have the rows and columns of the program change size (within minimum/maximum sizes) as the window is resized. I'll add the relevant code I have right now to my initial question.